# How to set php file to only serve for AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a website which uses AJAX Calls in a lot of places,
and all of them call to a single file, called `ajax_agent.php`
and with GET variables like `ajax_agent.php?action=x&arg1=y&etc=true`

But a nasty user can directly go to ajax_agent.php with custom variables. It uses prepared PDO statements, so no danger of sql injection I guess, but still it can reveal things that it shouldn't.

So is there any way to detect if the client is another php page (AJAX'ing it) or an actual browser window? So that it will `die('you don't have permission to see this page.');` ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use sessions to set permissions for what users have access to

Comment: Remember, javascript is a client-side executed language. If javascript can access a resource, so can a user

Comment: @Musa Ok, but in this case I don't want any of the "users" to browse that page. It should only echo something if it is an AJAX call.

Comment: @compid seems legit. So, no way?

Comment: @Musa — The session won't change between an Ajax request and an address bar request or a link-in-view-source request.

Comment: I've added an answer. still doesn't COMPLETELY prevent it because an malicious user can send a HTTP request with custom headers, but it's as good as it gets

Comment: AFAIK the only difference between an ajax call and a "standard" browser call is the addition of `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` in the header.  No matter what you do, if a malicious user wanted to they could very easily write an http client and manually add that header, or a referrer header or anything else that you might check.

Comment: @appclay — That doesn't get added by XHR by default.

Comment: @Quentin I'm suggesting a different approach

Comment: @Quentin maybe not but it always seems to be there!  Microsoft use the presence of that header to determine whether a request is an ajax request in the ASP.NET MVC framework, so I'm guessing it's fairly reliable.

Comment: @appclay — If you're writing JavaScript that adds the header, then it is a perfectly reasonable way to decide what format to present the response in. It's no good for security.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments. But why the downvotes? I don't care but I want to understand it. What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header. This relies on your whether your javascript (library) properly sends out this header, though:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  // do AJAX only stuff
}
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

**Edit**: Note that as I said in the question comments, if a request can be made with javascript, it can be made by humans. There is no way to prevent that. This answer just provides a way to filter out the average user visiting the page directly.

Comment: PHP configuration is largely irrelevant. It depends on the JavaScript that tells the client to make the request to set the header. Nothing stops the user from setting it themselves.

Comment: This is what Zend Framework uses to detect Ajax Requests for it context switcher.

Comment: Thanks ! I will accept your answer when it's available.

Comment: @Orangepill — It's OK for a system to serve an appropriate representation of the data. It doesn't work for security.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed but it would twart the casual observer. Anything coming from the client is untrustworthy

Comment: It is also important to note that this can easily be spoofed. It will prevent casual users from visiting a page that shows a bunch of JSON, but if someone really wanted to, they could set that header manually and bypass your check.

Answer (score 5):

An AJAX request is an HTTP request just like any other. Any part of the request could be manipulated by an attacker. You can't trust any part of it, so detecting that it's an Ajax request from a browser rather than a manipulated request through a browser won't be reliable.

If you really want to protect your data force a user to login and use sessions to enforce it.

Comment: Forcing the user to login won't prevent them from seeing the raw data. It just prevents anonymous users from seeing it. (There is no way to give data to the browser without letting the user access it directly)

Comment: Agreed, but if the PHP script refuses to process any requests from a user that's not logged in there's no leakage to anonymous users. I'm assuming a login system is somehow moderated to restrict access to trusted users.

Comment: Yes this is a good idea. But in my case, I don't want to implement a login system. Thanks anyway :)